# Internal Server Error for an ajax request from Visual Web Part to application page

Tags: application-pages, ajax, solution

I have Internal Server Error in response to 
an Ajax call. The request is sent from a Visual Web Part, inside a solution, towards an application page :

The application page has this method:

```
 [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
        public static String Creation()
        {
           // do something ...

                return "{\"status\":\"success\"}";

        }
```

The visual web part makes this JQuery call:

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",                    url: "/_layouts/15/PrenCalendarExchange/Registration.aspx/Creation",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    data: {
                        prenSubject: $('#prenSubject').val()
                        , location: $('#location').val()
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                             alert("Error: " + textStatus + " - " + errorThrown);
//INTRNAL SERVER ERROR IS THROWN HERE
                    }
                });
```

The call works fine in my local environment but fails on a test environment.

Comment: Are you able to access the ULS logs to identify what the internal server error is? Additionally, would you be able to wrap Creation in a try-catch to try and return a string version of the exception, if you're not able to directly debug?

Answer (score 0):

I used this syntax and it is working fine:

Application Page:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string myWB()
{
     return "my HTML or JSON"
}
```

The call from the visual web part is same as yours.
So maybe try to add just `[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]` to your method.